# Could not load file or assembly 'NetTopologySuite, Version=1.13.4693.18484

Tags: ravendb

ok, here's the situation.

I have two projects:

- ASP.NET MVC 4 (references class library)
- Class Library (Added RavenDB and Net Topology Suite from NuGet)

When I try to run 'SpatialGenerate' in any index, I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'NetTopologySuite, Version=1.13.4693.18484, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f580a05016ebada1' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I am using .net 4.5 of course and I'm doing this in VS 2012 on Windows 8. I have tried hosting this in IIS/IISexpress and the cassini server. I have checked that the file and it's related files are all present in the bin/debug directories and their versions are accurate. I also created a unit test that calls the queries via the index and I get the same error.

I have searched everywhere and I can't seem to find anything.  Furthermore, once I was able to execute the index and everything worked, but I don't know why and can't make it happen again.

Comment: How can I reproduce this? Can you open an issue about this here(http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/dashboard#newissue=yes), and specify the NuGet package that you used with the index that cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the RavenDB.Ebmedded package or add RavenDB.Database